# Embed iOS games into another iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, embed

I have a main app that will act as a portal for games (like Kongregate for example). When you choose a game then the game loads (without any additional download, just preloading on demand).

I'd like to keep my games appart from the main app and then embed them on the main project so I can make the games for example with StencylWorks (or just in another separated project) and my main app in xCode.

Which is the best way to achieve this? (I think what i want to do is most like embedding other SWF's into an adobe air app).

Thanks!

Comment: Careful with your implimentation of that. Per iOS Developer Guidelines apps cannot execute code that was not bundled with the application. So you can't download code and run it from your application.

Comment: Proceed carefully, friend, there be dark waters ahead... Apple isn't too  friendly to apps that might compete with iTunes... hence the rules against downloading code and running external code in your app. You should likely be okay if you bundle all the code though.

Comment: Don't bother. You won't be approved anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You write each game and 'start' them when you press the button. They have to be part of the application bundle itself.

You can not execute outside compiled code such as a `.swf`.